# SiriProxy reset config variable

Tags: ruby, rvm, siri

Ok here is my config section: It Pulls the variable from the config.yml file in the .siriproxy folder.

```
def initialize(config)
@hs_host = config["hs_host"]
@speak_response = config["speak_response"]
```

end

Now I want to make a listen command that can change the @speak_response variable and make it available to any other listen command in the rb file.

For instace a command that when I say "turn speak off" sets the @speak_response to "off".
I understand how to do this within the listen command but not how to make it so the speak_response is set for any listen command in the whole rb file.

Answer (score 0):

Guess I need to write a config file. Got it figured out.